PrimeVue DataTable loads very slow with 2000+ records (15s), compared to Vue.js + basic html table (2s)
I'm having performance issues with the PrimeVue Datatable, and would like some help to understand how to find the issue and fix it. With 2000+ records, the DataTable loads very slowly, minimum 5 seconds, sometimes 20 or more seconds.
With a basic Vue.js component and a standard html table, the same dataset loads in 2 seconds.
I know there's VirtualScroller and Pagination for normal scenarios, but in our specific use case we need to have the table working as is without those. Im certain the issue is in the PrimeVue code, because of the comparison with the basic datatable.
Any ideas where I can start to look at fixing it? This is a dealbreaker for using PrimeVue, and we really want to get to the bottom of this, as we like the rest of the PrimeVue component suite and layout templates that we've already purchased.

Code example showing the loading time issues with PrimeVue DataTable

Code example showing the much faster load time using a basic HTML table component


I'm even happy to try to diagnose and help fix the issue for PrimeTek with a Pull Request, but need some help to find where to start looking for the cause of the slowness.

It's only suspect as im not similar with PrimeVue yet, but it makes a lot of component's
I don't know the case but there probably should be used paggination to pages 2000 records is quiet big amount to show at once

Yep pagination normally will help, but for our use case, we need to be able to figure out why its so much slower than the non-datatable version. It has to be an issue in the primevue table. Just dont know where to start to look and fix it.

So as i said im quiet sure its abut how many options and components PrimveVue tries to generate for each row, while u make it with basic html / vue you probably do it quiet straigt forward - only what you need to generate but PrimeVue have a lots of preconfigurations that have to be executed 2000 times and check if u dont want that feature or other feature for datatable and PrimeVue component is probbly written to be extendable over speed performace

There's also a lot of "" inside rendered code (you can checkup it by debug generated html in dev tools) which offten represent's v-if statement so for each of this theres extra logic under to check something

Thanks for the insights Damian, yes I have considered the extra features adding complexity and further checked and processing, unavoidable, so hopefully we can find another reason for the slowness. And sadly quite frustrating that someone has down voted my question without explaining why, and not mentioning how to improve the question. Very unhelpful themselves.

This is not really a solution, so I'm just posting this update as a comment, but in the end, this issue was a dealbreaker, so we went with an in-house solution, which renders 2000+ records fine without virtual scrollers etc. I think (as said by others above) it was likely due to the calculations and checks and internal sub components within each table row and cell, in order to allow the PrimeVue table to be as feature rich as it is. So for our purposes, the only option was to make our own table that contained only the functionality we needed there. Made a world of difference in performance.
